# What condition needs to be met before a type of matter dominates the density of the universe

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

If we're given some theory about the expansion of the universe such as particles being created at some time t and having a density related to their critical density at that time for example and we want to know at what time they come to dominate the density of the universe What are we actually trying to show ?

i.e. What condition must be met so that this is true ?

can we just figure out the time by using the friedmann eq for matter dominated universe and inputting our conditions and integrating ?

Is that correct or what is the condition we seek ?

Answer (score 1):

The condition is that the density should be mostly the density of that component. For example, during radiation domination, most of the density (which could theoretically be greater, equal to, or less than the critical density) was in light species. The energy density of light species decreases like $1/a^4$. On the other hand, the density of heavy species ($mc^2 > k_B T$) decreases slower, like $1/a^3$. Eventually, the density of light species will become less than the density of heavy species and the density will be mostly in heavy species. This is called matter domination. Dark energy density, however, is constant and does not decrease. Eventually it will dominate everything in an expanding universe.

Comment: In terms of the friedmann equations though and saying we want to solve for the time at which this happens then should we just plug those density profiles into the equation and integrate from there in order to find the exact time?

Comment: I understand the general idea, I'm just confused as to how to describe this mathemathically for precise calculations

Comment: I think you write something like $\int dt = \int \frac{da}{\dot a} = \int \frac{da}{Ha}$ and replace $H=H_0\sqrt{\Omega_r {a^-4} + \Omega_m a^{-3}}$.